# Accessing parameters from POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have an HTML form in my Rails view

```
<form id="download_form" action="download">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit_download_form" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How do I access the value of the parameter `username` in the Rails controller `download` method?

Comment: This is not a good practise. You'd better take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Where specifically would you recommend that I look at?

Comment: I just wanted to make you remember about using form helpers instead of pure html. They have many advantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access your paremeters by doing `params[:username]` in your controller.